# Как системно вернуться на рабочий стол?

Tags: java, android

У меня на телефоне перестали работать сенсорные кнопки.

Решил сделать так, чтобы сверху в тлф висело уведомление, при нажатии на которое открывался рабочий стол.
Собственно как системно открыть рабочий стол (т.е. сымитировать нажатие на кнопку "Домашний экран")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void backHome() {
    Intent home = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    home.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(home);
}
```

Comment: Может подскажете, как открыть и список запущенный приложений?
Пробовал разные категории  и флаги -- не получилось никак.